# How to use strcmp() to compare a returned value of a function to a function call in a loop?

Tags: matlab

The issue I'm having is I am attempting to compare the result of the fireShot() command to the outcome 'Splash'.  Next I need to tally the total true values (or everytime fireShot()= 'Splash').  However, everytime I attempt to use either a while loop or a if loop I end up with a constant number (that does not match up with the appropriate random number or my preceding function on their respective plots).  I am sure the formatting of this is not very appeasing and could use work but my real problem lies with, I believe, the tallying of the values of strcmp().

Anyways this is my code:

```
function [ output_args ] = fireShots(shotstofire, fieldSize, pondRadius)
%// This function will fire multiple shots and count how many of them     
%// land in the pond.

    %// Counts down total number of shots and subtracts 1 until
    %// total is equal to '0'    
    while shotstofire > 0
        shotstofire;
        shotstofire = shotstofire - 1;

        %// Calls fireShot function
        Splash = fireShot(fieldSize,pondRadius);
        Land = strcmp(Splash,'Splash');
    end

    %// If the ball hits inside the pond
    %// Land (total tally) gets +1
    if (Land)
        Land = Land + 1;
    else

    end        
end
```

I know my code may be off, but all my functions up to this function work like they are supposed to.

Comment: what kind of strings do you get from fireShot? Also, if you use strcmp it's going to do a case-sensitive string match, if you want case-insensitive then use strcmpi

Comment: well the fireShot calls a random variable function that generates 2 points that are plotted on a graph.  If the 2 points generated are in a circle (0,0) with radius 1 then I am returned "Splash" if they are outside of the radius I get "thud".  However; I have defined Splash to =fireShot in this because I attempted to try to use something I found online that related an input variable to a yes or no question by means of strcpm().  I figured since I had only 2 returns to choose from I could attempt to use similar coding but may have made it more confusing.

Comment: My issue is I believe The strcmp(Splash,'Splash') works but I cannot figure out how to tally the true values. We I call the function in the command window it gives me a list of all the outcomes (Splash or Thud) plots the points on the graph but when the Land variable comes up at the end it = 2.  I am guessing that 1 (for strcmp being true) +1 from the if statement I made with Land = Land + 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then your problem is actually just a logic error; the strcmp check is fine, you just have to move your `Land` tallying logic inside your while loop to get the number of total shots that are 'Splash'es. As it is, you will at most get +1 to your `Land` variable, depending on the result of the last `strcmp`, as you perform your check and increment outside of your while loop.

```
function [ output_args ] = fireShots(shotstofire, fieldSize, pondRadius)
    %// This function will fire multiple shots and count how many of them     
    %// land in the pond.

    %// Counts down total number of shots and subtracts 1 until
    %// total is equal to '0'    
    while shotstofire > 0
        shotstofire;
        shotstofire = shotstofire - 1;

        %// Calls fireShot function
        Splash = fireShot(fieldSize,pondRadius);

        %// If the ball hits inside the pond
        %// Land (total tally) gets +1
        if (strcmp(Splash,'Splash'))
            Land = Land + 1;
        end
    end      
end
```

Comment: My only issue is the Land variable is undefined.  How exactly could I define this.  I previously set it = to the strcmp(Splash,'Splash') function, however you using it with the If statement makes me think I cannot do this anymore.

Comment: @MikeFritz Set it to 0 initially, i.e. when you first enter the function (assuming you start with 0 splashes that is)